# Finding the area of surface obtained by rotating $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2, 0 < r < a$, about the line $x = -a$.

Tags: calculus

So I solved this problem by using parametric euqations, where x= a + r cos t and y = a  +r sin t. Then got the answer 8$\pi r^2a$. But the answer sheet keeps saying that it is 16$\pi ra$. I'm not sure who's right.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us through your entire working?

Comment: What's on the paper is not what you wrote in the answer.  You got $8\pi^2ra$ on the paper and wrote $8\pi r^2a$.  I agree with your paper answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[Pappus's Centroid Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html) says that the area of a surface of revolution is equal to the length of the rotated curve times the distance the centroid travels.

In this case the rotated curve is a circle, and its circumference is $2\pi r$.  The centroid of the circle is the center $(a,b)$.  It travels around a circle of radius $2a$, for a distance of $2\pi(2a) = 4\pi a$.

Therefore the surface area is $(2\pi r)(4\pi a) = 8 \pi^2 r a$.